# Are $\lVert \Delta u \rVert_{L^2(S)}$ and $\lVert u \rVert_{H^2(S)}$ equivalent norms on a compact manifold?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, dg.differential-geometry

Hi,

I am looking for the result:
$$\text{The norm} \quad \lVert \Delta u \rVert_{L^2(S)} \quad \text{is equivalent to} \quad \lVert u \rVert_{H^2(S)}$$
for scalar functions $u \in H^2(S)$, where $S$ is a compact hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so in particular it's a compact manifold with no boundary. I know this result holds in the flat case (but have yet to prove that) for $H^2_0$ functions so I am hoping it just carries through.

Is this true? Can somebody give me a reference to this or show/tell me how to prove it?
I tried books by Aubin, Hebey and Michael E. Taylor but I did not find anything.f
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the correspondence

$$u\mapsto\Vert \Delta u\Vert_{L^2(S)} $$

is not a norm because   if $u$ is constant, then $ \Delta u=0$. The correspondence

$$ u\mapsto \Vert u\Vert_{L^2(S)}+  \Vert \Delta u\Vert_{L^2(S)} $$

is a norm equivalent with $\Vert u\Vert_{H^2(S)}$ because of the elliptic a priori estimates which state that if $L: C^\infty(S)\to C^\infty(S)$ is a 2nd order elliptic operator on $S$ with smooth coefficients, then there exists a constant $C>0$ such that

$$ \Vert  u\Vert_{H^2(S)}\leq C\Bigl(\;  \Vert u\Vert_{L^2(S)}+  \Vert L u\Vert_{L^2(S)}\;\Bigr),\;\;\forall u\in H^2(S). $$

The Laplacian $\Delta: C^\infty(S)\to C^\infty(S)$  is  such an operator.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. Please can you recommend a reference for this result?

Comment: Try chapter 10 of mu notes http://www.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf

Comment: @Liviu I tried your notes but could only find a proof for the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case (theorem 10.3.1). is the intention that this result carries for the manifold case?

Comment: I have not proved it for $\mathbb{R}^n$ because, in this case,  *it is false  for many second order elliptic operators*. One needs some    assumptions about the behavior at $\infty$  of the coefficients of $L$.  It is true when $L=\Delta$,  and this follows easily using the Fourier  theoretic definition of the Sobolev spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if what you're looking for is just the following simple identity. Say $u$ is either a periodic function, or a function with compact support in $\mathbb R^d$, then we integrate by parts to obtain
$$
\int |\Delta u|^2 = \int \partial_{ii} u \partial_{jj} u = - \int \partial_i u \partial_{ijj} u = \int \partial_{ij} u \partial_{ij} u = \int |D^2 u|^2$$

If you give the right definitions to $\Delta u$ and $D^2 u$ on any compact Riemannian manifold $S$, a similar computation should go through.

Comment: Yes (if one uses covariant derivatives), though there will be lower order curvature terms emerging related to the Bochner and Weitzenbock identities. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_identity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weitzenböck_identity

Comment: Beside the curvature issues  indicated by Terry Tao,   the above argument relies on the fact that $u$ vanishes  along the boundary of a large ball. If  $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$  is a  bounded domain with smooth boundary, then $\Vert\Delta u\Vert_{L^2}$ is indeed a norm on the space of functions vanishing along the boundary. It is NOT a norm  on the  full space  $H^2(D)$.